# Logging a Daemon's Output with Upstart

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I have a custom daemon that is managed by upstart on my Ubuntu server. It works perfectly except that I need to capture (log) the daemon's output. The [official stanzas page](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#console) says that I can use `console logged` to do this, but what file does it log to?

I've also read that `console logged` is [no longer a valid stanza](http://geeknme.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/getting-started-with-upstart-in-ubuntu/). I'm currently using 0.3.9 (Hardy) but will upgrade to 0.6.x (Lucid) in a few months. If `console logged` in fact won't work with later versions, what do I use instead?

Comment: Can you simply update your custom daemon to send the output to syslog, or to a logfile specified in the daemon's configuration file?

Answer (score 36):

This snippet will pipe the output of your service
into logger, while still allowing you to exec the
service process (thus replacing the shell process)
so that upstart doesn't get confused. It also makes
sure the logger process is reparented to init, so
it's not a child of your service, and it avoids
leaving cruft sitting around in the filesystem, even
though it needs to create a fifo temporarily.

```
script
  mkfifo /tmp/myservice-log-fifo
  ( logger -t myservice </tmp/myservice-log-fifo & )
  exec >/tmp/myservice-log-fifo
  rm /tmp/myservice-log-fifo
  exec myservice 2>/dev/null
end script
```

Here's how it works:

1. `mkfifo /tmp/myservice-log-fifo` simply makes the fifo special file
   (aka named pipe). Type `man 7 fifo` for more info.
2. `( logger ... </tmp/myservice-log-fifo & )`  starts logger reading from the fifo, in the background. The parens cause the logger process to be reparented to init, rather than remaining a child of the current shell process.
3. `exec >/tmp/myservice-log-fifo` redirects the current shell's stdout to the fifo. Now we have an open file descriptor for that fifo, and we don't actually need the filesystem entry any more...
4. `rm /tmp/myservice-log-fifo` so we'll remove it.
5. `exec myservice 2>/dev/null` simply runs the service in the usual way. Stdout is already going to the fifo, and that won't change when the new program executes.

**UPDATE:** `set -e` is not needed as Upstart runs scripts with this option by default (see  http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#develop-scripts-using-bin-sh)

Comment: great answer, and doesn't leave fifo files lying around anywhere.

Comment: What is the `set -e`?

Comment: The `set -e` causes the script to exit immediately if any command fails. Without that line, the script would continue running subsequent commands uselessly (and possibly dangerously).

Comment: To log stderr as well as stdout, add the line `exec 2>&1` above the `rm` line, and remove the `2>/dev/null` from the last line.

Answer (score 32):

For recent Ubuntu versions (12.04+), simply use

```
console log
```

And the daemon output (STDOUT & STDERR) will be appended to `/var/log/upstart/<service>.log`

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#console-log

Comment: That would be clean and nice, but unfortunately it doesn't work on CentOS 6.x which still ships an ancient version of upstart that doesn't support this.

Answer (score 11):

If you use the `console output` [stanza](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#console-output), and then pipe your script's output to `logger` (the shell command interface to the syslog(3) system log module) then that will work.

For example

```
console output
exec /my/script | logger
```

will log to `/var/log/messages`

For example

```
console output
exec /my/script | logger -t my-script
```

will log to `/var/log/messages` and tag each message with `my-script`

`logger --help` for logger usage options.

(I'm on the Amazon Linux AMI, which is Centos 5.x based; YMMV)

Comment: It turns out this isn't a good solution. upstart latches onto the PID of `logger`, not of the process you actually want it to manage.

Answer (score 11):

I did not get the `mkfifo` trick to work satisfactorily; it did not seem to capture stderr, and attempts to redirect caused Upstart to bail with no errors.

It also has an unfortunate side effect of making the `logger` process hang around as a child of `init`, so the information about who "owns" the logger is lost, and anyone not already aware of the `mkfifo` might assume it's a dangling process that can be killed.

Instead I ended up with the following solution, which resolves all of these issues. It causes `logger` to become a child process, while preserving the service as the root process. Unfortunately, it requires exec'ing `bash`, but it just *looks* dirty.

```
script
  # ... setup commands here, e.g. environment, cd, ...
  exec bash <<EOT
    exec 1> >(logger -t myservice) 2>&1
    exec myservice
EOT
end script
```

This uses a trick that redirects stdout and stderr to a command. Since we exec the service inside the `bash` command, this has the side effect of replacing the shell and magically making bash become a child process of the service, as shown by `ps aufxw`:

```
myservice 
 \_ bash -c exec 1> >(logger -t myservice) 2>&1 && exec myservice
    \_ logger -t myservice
```

For some reason the above command has to be wrapped in a `bash -c`. I assume this is because Upstart only pretends to run your script via Bash, but isn't actually. If anyone can suggest a way to avoid the extra bash shell, that would be awesome.

Comment: Yes!  I'm so glad I found this.  Looks better than the mkfifo variant and in my case I needed to `exec bash -l << EOF` so no loss there.

Answer (score 6):

This is ugly but so far the best I have found

exec /path/to/server >> /tmp/upstart.log 2>&1

Comment: The solution is not a good when it comes to log rotation, because the application is logging directly to the file. Logging through syslog avoids related problems.

Answer (score 3):

You can also redirect the output to syslog, e.g.

```
exec $SERVER 2>&1 | logger -t myservice -p local0.info
```

However, the pipeline may cause upstart to confuse the PID of the logging process with the PID of the daemon.

Comment: The daemon confusing the PID is actually a useless daemon, since it is supposed to watch the process, respawn it then. Any idea on how to make sure the right PID is being watched?

Comment: I think (but haven't tried) that you'll want the `expect fork` or `expect daemon` stanza.  Or you could `cat` the pid-file into the log message otherwise, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is using tee like:

```
exec $SERVER 2>&1 | tee /dev/stderr | logger -t myservice
```

to get both upstart file, and syslog output